# Adjusting vertical spacing in nested lists

Tags: spacing, lists, koma-script

I am using the `scrreprt` class with `parskip=full` and would like to adjust the vertical spacing in nested lists. I am already using the `enumitem` package and specifying the `nosep` option for level 2 lists, but can't find a way to remove the spacing at the top of the nested list. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlist[2]{nosep}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  Outer item 1

  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    Nested item 1
  \item
    Nested item 2
  \item
    Nested item 3
  \end{itemize}
\item
  Outer item 2
\item
  Outer item 3
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Specifically I want to get rid of the extra spacing between "Outer item 1" and the first item in the nested list ("Nested item 1"). Is it possible to do that globally, in a way that would affect all nested lists in a document (i.e. without resorting to manual vspace tweaks and the like) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch of `parskip` at the begin of the list:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlist[2]{nosep,before=\KOMAoptions{parskip=false}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[66]

\begin{enumerate}
\item
  Outer item 1
  \begin{itemize}
  \item
    Nested item 1
  \item
    Nested item 2
  \item
    Nested item 3
  \end{itemize}
\item
  Outer item 2
\item
  Outer item 3
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}
```

[image: only the top space]